# Jquery PHP form submit - How to get form inputs to display?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I have a contact form > www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_3.php
it uses jquery validate and PHP. I have some add/ remove class bits to hide or reveal a Thank you title and some php if isset to echo back the successful form submission inputs.

My problem is that on submission you see the thank you page but the div> sadhu is not showing the data that the user input... infact its not displaying as a div - please help

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contactform').validate({
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   //restore the normal look
   $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
   //stop if everything is ok
   if (errorList.length == 0) return;
   //Iterate over the errors
   for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
   $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
},
submitHandler: function(form) {             
    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append('#sadhu');
    $('#contactform').hide();
    var usr = document.getElementById('contactname').value;
    var eml = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
    document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
    form.submit();
}
});
});
```

Here is my PHP:

```
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
}
```

And here is my FORM:

```
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform" >
        <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">Name*</p><input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" /></div><br/><br/>
        <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">E-mail address*</p><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" /></div><br/><br/>
        <p class="label_left">Message</p><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<div id='sadhu'>` is not defined anywhere.  You're appending it to `#content` with Javascript code, but it doesn't exist.

```
$("#content").append('#sadhu');
```

You might want something like

```
$("#content").append("<div id='sadhu'>stuff in here...</div>");
```

You have placed the form entries into something with the id `out`.  If that stuff should also be in `<div id='sadhu'>`, then you can just place the `.html()` of `out` into it:

```
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
$("#content").append("<div id='sadhu'>" + $("#out").html() + "</div>");
```

Comment: right thanks Michael.... but heres the thing the Stuff in between should be whats been entered in the form by the user. How should I be doing that - as for now I have it as php echo variables.